# Incorrect click event when resize on libGdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to use scene2D, in libGDX, to detect click on object.

I have this simple Game sample :

```
Stage stage;

@Override
public void create()
{      
    this.stage = new Stage(1280, 720, true);
    MyActor actor = new MyActor();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    actor.setTexture(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("plateau.jpg"))));
    actor.setScale(0.1f);

    stage.addActor(actor);        

    actor.addListener(new InputListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
            System.out.println("down"+Math.random());
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void render()
{
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

MyActor is a simple class extending Actor with a rendertexture.
The Event is working fine at start.
But when resizing the frame, while the Actor is streched as wanted, the coordinates of the click are not updated and thus misplaced.

How to make the stage using the new size of the items as base to the event ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the viewport of your stage in resize method of your application like this:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    stage.setViewport(stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight(), false, 0, 0, width, height);

}
```

Comment: Depending on which version of libgdx he uses, it might have to be `stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.width, Gdx.graphics.height, true)`

Comment: Your solutions are working ; however they resize the viewport, keeping the sprites at the same size, and my layout gets out of the frame. I need the images to actually stretch, making the game layout same at different sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure if i can help then, the code above is directly from my game and it does actually stretch everything when resized.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was similar to what mentioned above but you have to modify it slightly:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

You shouldn't use the Gdx.graphics.width and height but really use what resize() is providing to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use camera.project() method for this purpose I think.

camera.project(Vector3 worldPoint);

Does this works for you?